# CodeIgniter multiple applications htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I wan't to divide my CI into multiple applications. I should say that it is within a folder called app on the root /var/www/app/. First I tried this setup:

```
/system/
/application/
  /app1/
  /app2/
app1.php
app2.php
.htaccess
```

But I couldn't get my htaccess to point correctly. Therefore I went ahead with this:

```
/system/
/app1/
  .htaccess
  /application/
  index.php
/app2/
  .htaccess
  /application/
  index.php
```

And now it works fine with urls: mysite.com/app/app1/index.php/welcome - but I would like to hide index.php from the URL. Therefore my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|gfx|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

However it is not working, I get 404 when trying to access mysite.com/app/app1/welcome.
Could someone clarify whats wrong with my .htaccess? I have another .htaccess on the root and will run some wordpress from there, but would it affect my /app folder where CI runs?
Thank you so much!

Comment: How about this http://www.highermedia.com/articles/nuts_bolts/tutorial_advanced_codeigniter_installation

Comment: What exactly are you referring to here? The cleaner urls? I've already tried that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so it's working now. After some hours of debugging. I'm not sure exactly what did the trick, but I think I was missing a `AllowOverride All` in my default vhost. After apache restart and this htaccess in every /app/app1/ folder it started working:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|gfx|css|app|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Thanks to everyone who contributed to my question.

Answer (score 3):

Try to add this one on each folder (from http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Did not change anything, tried to put it into my app1 folder.

Comment: Sorry, change the `RewriteBase` to `RewriteBase /app/app1/`

Comment: By the way. Do you get Apache 404 or Code Igniter 404?

Comment: I get CI 404, and I tried the RewriteBase before when you posted, and didn't work. Just tried again.

Comment: If you get CI's 404, the .htaccess is working. You probably just don't have the "welcome" controller or the `index` method on it.

Comment: But how come mysite.com/app/app1/index.php/welcome work and not mysite.com/app/app1/welcome work then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12849/discussion-between-designer-and-jlcd)

Answer (score 0):

Does it work after you add a RewriteBase directive?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /app1/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|gfx|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: No unfortunately not. I should have said that earlier. I tried with RewriteBase /app/app1/ and RewriteBase /app1/ but still not working.

Comment: Does codeigniter have some sort of config file where it stores its base URL?