# Accessing multiple applications in Code Igniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, project

I have two applications in one Code Igniter project.

```
application
  --PW1
  --PW2
```

This is the directory structure. I changed the application_folder in index.php

```
$application_folder = 'application/PW2';
```

This works fine. I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135711/codeigniter-multiple-applications-htaccess).

What I would like to do is access the second application from the first one. How can I do that. First I tried the simple solution:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>application/PW1">
```

But access is forbidden this way. How can I do this?

Comment: Will these 2 applications share the same database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/managing_apps.html) . It states that

> Note:  Each of your applications will need its own index.php file which calls the desired application. The index.php file can be named anything you want.

So according to the folder structure you have created, it should look something like this

```
system
application
----PW1
----index.php (with $application_folder = 'application/PW1';)
----PW2
----index.php (with $application_folder = 'application/PW2';)
```

Comment: Ok, though the index.php should be one level higher with distinct names. Why did you ask about the database, are there any problems with this.

Comment: No there are no problems with this, i asked because if you used different databases for each project, you might had to do some more alterations.