# 2 codeigniter applications & htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, apache2, raspberry-pi

I had a codeigniter proyect working in windows with XAMPP and now I was moving it to my RaspberryPi:

1. Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
2. PHP 5.4.4-14+deb7u5
3. mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31

I have two codeignitir aplications (principal and panel) with this estructure

```
/ -> (apache root folder)
/appname/admin 
        /admin/application/ -> (codeigniter application to panel)
/appname/application/ -> (codeigniter application to public)
```

Now I can't access to admin controllers and I think is because .htaccess. I get this in some url:
my.domain/appname -> codeigniter welcome for public (this part is empty so I think is OK)
my.domain/appname/admin/login.html -> Not Found. The requested URL /mydomain/admin/login was not found on this server.
my.domain/appname/admin/index.php?controller=admin -> 404 Page Not Found (codeigniter style)
my.domain/appname/admin/hello.html -> hello (a dummy file I put to try, works ok)

In my codeigniter panel proyect I have

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://my.domain/myapp/admin/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
$config['url_suffix'] = '.html';
```

I think it's all about .htaccess but I don't understand them. How many files I need? What folders?

I had this .htaccess in my /appname & /appname/panel before

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /appname #to panel /appname/panel

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#‘system’ can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn’t true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#This last condition enables access to the images and css folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css)
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] 
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don’t have mod_rewrite installed, all 404’s
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I think RewriteEngine on is activated in my apache2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution by .htaccess inside admin's folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /appname/admin

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'appname' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^appname.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

[CodeIgniter multiple applications htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135711/codeigniter-multiple-applications-htaccess)

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_-]+)\.html$ index.php/page/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|asset|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```