# Codeigniter multiple application

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm new to .htaccess.
I have two CodeIgniter Project.

I have structured my project like this

```
parent-folder
--frontend (my frontend codeigniter project)
--backend (my backend codeigniter project)
```

when I hit example.com it should go to frontend and when I hit example.com/admin it should go to backend.

I'm not getting how to implement using .htaccess.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 codeigniter applications & htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875247/2-codeigniter-applications-htaccess)

Comment: Are you using CI 3 HMVC

Comment: @Uchiha Yes, I'm using CI 3

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
parent-folder(your frontend codeigniter project)
--admin (your backend codeigniter project)
```

your front end CI project must be in the root folder and the admin directory must be inside the root folder it need two separate `.htaccess` files. All files and folders inside `frontend` folder must be transferred to the parent-folder.

like this:

```
parent-folder
--.htaccess(.htaccess for your frontend)
--admin
----.htaccess(.htaccess for you admin)
```

just make sure to specify  your `admin .htaccess` file that youre are in the admin folder in the  `RewriteBase`.

**parent-folder:**

```
RewriteBase /
```

**admin**

```
 RewriteBase /admin
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

As Vien Mar has given the answer.

I figured out that if you keep the directory structure as

```
parent-folder(your frontend codeigniter project)
 --admin (your backend codeigniter project)
```

You can get the project running without extra effort. No need of .htaccess file as well.